# Using SDL_Cursor with unique_ptr : error incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++, sdl, unique-ptr, handle

I am trying to create a `unique_ptr` of type `SDL_Cursor`, but am unable to do so as the `SDL_Cursor` definition is within one of SDL's .dll files.

#### The SDL_Cursor struct is declared but not defined in SDL_mouse.h:

```
typedef struct SDL_Cursor SDL_Cursor;
```

So I keep getting the error:

> E0070 incomplete type is not allowed
>
> use of undefined type 'SDL_Cursor'

Is there any way to extract the definition of `SDL_Cursor` from the .dll file to avoid this error?

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <memory>
#include "SDL.h"

SDL_Cursor* p = SDL_CreateSystemCursor(SDL_SYSTEM_CURSOR_ARROW); - How it is usually created

SDL_Cursor* p = new SDL_Cursor(); - Undefined type error.

std::unique_ptr<SDL_Cursor> unique = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Cursor>(new SDL_Cursor()); - Undefined type error.
```

I am aware I would provide a custom deleter (`SDL_FreeCursor`) to the `unique_ptr` aswell, but even that doesn't work at present due to this error.

How can I get the definition of `SDL_Cursor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple reasons you don't really want to get types SDL hides from you. Even if you get that, it may change in future SDL version, and even in that case `new`ing cursor achieves nothing. In any case, use SDL creation/destruction functions, e.g.:

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Cursor, decltype(&SDL_FreeCursor)> p = {SDL_CreateSystemCursor(SDL_SYSTEM_CURSOR_ARROW), SDL_FreeCursor};
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I agree that makes sense. I needed the definition to be able to parse the unique ptr properly to a file (so I could load all cursor settings in one go) but seems more hassle than its worth. Thanks